# Cannot insert a breakpoint in shared Library

Tags: c++, gdb

Friends

While debugging an application of of the function is defined in a shared library which is written by another vendor . 
and I get an error like

warning: Cannot insert breakpoint 0: in /opt/trims/uat/lib/libTIPS_Oleca.sl

warning: This is because your shared libraries are not mapped private. To attach to a process and debug its shared libraries you must prepare the program with
**"/opt/langtools/bin/pxdb -s on a.out  or "chatr +dbg enable a.out ".****

warning: Add this to your Makefile for debug builds
warning: so that each rebuilt debuggable a.out would
warning: have this feature turned on.
Temporarily disabling shared library breakpoints:0

Now the problem is I cannot modify the shared library . 
How do I resolve this error ?
Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *don't need* to modify the shared library.

Instead, you *must* modify your main executable (by running `pxdb -s` or `chatr +dbg enable` on it).

The `a.out` in the message you are getting refers to your main executable -- it's a UNIX convention that the output from linker is called `a.out` if you don't explicitly name it.

Comment: You have a mistake in the name of the command: `chatr +dbg enable ./has_serverd`

Comment: http://h21007.www2.hp.com/portal/download/files/unprot/STK/HPUX_STK/libscan.html#sharedlibs

Comment: I have a similar question but I don't know what pxdb or chatr is. Can anyone please help me? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727803/cannot-insert-a-breakpoint-in-shared-library